# Need An Element To Move Position When It's Reached On The Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, css-transitions

I have 3 blocks about halfway down the page that the client wants to appear in an upward transition when the user scrolls down to it. I've been looking into transition on scroll effects all morning and most of what I've found are parallax pages and headers.

```
<ul class="testimoniallist">
<li>
stuff
</li>
<li>
more stuff
</li>
<li>
Other stuff
</li>
```

- User goes to the website
- User scrolls down to the section with that UL and the three list items
- The three list items then appear to transition up

Just for testing purposes, I created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/odyq4rc7/

I gave the ul class a margin top of 1600px so when the user scrolls down to it, how could I bump that up 100px when it comes into viewport view?

Answer (score 1):

On scroll, you could check if the element has come into view, and set its properties accordingly, using something like this to check if its in the viewport:

```
function isScrolledIntoView( element ) {
    var elementTop    = element.getBoundingClientRect().top,
        elementBottom = element.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

    return elementTop >= 0 && elementBottom <= window.innerHeight;
}
```

Comment: Whelp, I feel really stupid. I was pulling my hair out trying to get this and another example to work and I looked to the left and didn't have any jQuery libraries selected. I ended up figuring it out with this http://jsfiddle.net/odyq4rc7/30/

I can use it as a baseline and then give it the functionality they need.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following: (I found this courtesy of this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vVaat/76/)

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var $window = $(window),
        docViewTop = $window.scrollTop(),
        docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height(),
        elemTop = $(elem).offset().top,
        elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).outerHeight();
    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

$(window).on("scroll", function() {

    $('.testimoniallist').each(function() {
        if (isScrolledIntoView(this)) {
            $(this).addClass('yes');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('yes');
        }
    });

});
```